# .dir_colors を定義しても、ディレクトリとファイルの色が同色になってしまう

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin

ログイン先のサーバーにてディレクトリとファイルの色が全て白色に表示されてしまいます．
最初に /etc/DIR_COLORS をホームディレクトリに .dir_colors としてコピーしました．

~/.dir_colors の中身の一部は以下の通りです．

```sh
# Below are the color init strings for the basic file types. A color init
# string consists of one or more of the following numeric codes:
# Attribute codes:
# 00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed
# Text color codes:
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
# Background color codes:
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
NORMAL 00       # global default, although everything should be something.
FILE 00         # normal file
DIR 01;34       # directory
LINK 01;36      # symbolic link
FIFO 40;33      # pipe
SOCK 01;35      # socket
BLK 40;33;01    # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01    # character device driver
ORPHAN 01;05;37;41  # orphaned syminks
MISSING 01;05;37;41 # ... and the files they point to

# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32
```

これを ~/.bashrc に `` eval `dircolors .dir_colors -b` `` を追加し、`source .bashrc` と実行したのですが，ファイルもディレクトリも白色のままでした．

`echo $LS_COLORS` としても何も表示されません．
何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: `grep -E "^TERM $TERM$" ~/.dir_colors` の実行結果はどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis ホームディレクトリでそのコマンドを実行しましたがなにも表示されません

Comment: `/etc/DIR_COLORS` をコピーした後、`TERM` で始まる行を削除していたりしないでしょうか？ もしくは環境変数 TERM を設定していない、設定しているとしても dircolors が受け付けない設定値になっていることなどが考えられます。

Comment: echo $TERMの変数がDIR_COLORSに記載されていませんでした．コピーした.dir_colorsの中にTERMを追加したところ無事に解決しました．ありがとうございます．
ちなみにエイリアスでls='ls --color'としても解決しました．

Answer (score 1):

`echo $TERM`の変数が`DIR_COLORS`に記載されていませんでした．コピーした`.dir_colors`の中に`TERM`を追加し‌​たところ無事に解決しました．

ちなみにエイリアスで`ls='ls --color'`としても解決しました．

<sub>-- [質問者](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26604/tm-y)さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40767/%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E8%89%B2%E3%81%8C%E5%90%8C%E8%89%B2%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86#comment41587_40767)より。アイディアは [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[このコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40767/%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E8%89%B2%E3%81%8C%E5%90%8C%E8%89%B2%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86#comment41583_40767)に由来します。</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
eval `dircolors .dir_colors -b`
```

ではなく、

```
eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors -b`
```

にする必要があると思います。（`~/`が抜けています）

Comment: eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors -b`に変更しても結果は変わりませんでした